# Power automate flow" monitor incoming emails to an alias in an excel worksheet. I can not add the body of the email to the flow

Tags: excel, outlook

I am using the o365. in a web version of excel, I used the automate tab, and used the out of the box flow "monitor incoming emails to an alias in an excel worksheet". It worked and out of the box the worksheet is updated with senderemail, subject, message preview, and recieveddatetime.

I want to add the body of the email as one of the data fields that get updated. In the flow, in the "add a row into a table" in the row field, I simply added the line to add body. Here is the code:

`{ "SenderEmail":From", "Subject": " Subject", **"Body": "Body"** "MessagePreview": "Body Preview", "ReceivedDateTime": "formatDate",` 
This did not add the body of the message as expected. the other fields work. What do I need to change to the template as this is the only change I made.

thanks